# What is a homotopy between bisimplicial maps

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am looking for the naive notion of homotopy.

For maps $f, g: A\to B$ of simplicial sets $\Delta^{op}\to Sets$, a homotopy $H$ is a simplicial map $H:A\times\Delta^{1}\to B$ such that $H|_{A\times\{0\}}=f$ and $H|_{A\times\{1\}}=g$, or equivalently a collection of maps $H_i: X_n\to Y_{n+1}, 0\le i\le n$ subject to a bunch of identities, see [encyclopedia of math](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Simplicial_object_in_a_category).

Now for maps $f, g:A\to B$ of bisimplicial sets $\Delta^{op}\times\Delta^{op}\to Sets$, what is a homotopy between them?

Is it a map $A\times\Delta^{1,1}\to B$ such that a suitable boudary condition hold? But now there are four vertexes of $\Delta^{1,1}$.

Obviously, we may define a map $A\times\Delta^{0,1}\to B$ or $A\times\Delta^{1,0}\to B$ to be vertical/horizontal homotopy.

Comment: This depends on what kind of homotopical structure you put on the category of bisimplicial sets. In particular, you may want to look into the Quillen model structures on bisimplicial sets. I would look into Goerss and Jardine's book on simplicial homotopy theory.

Comment: @BabyDragon Yes, I am aware of it, that is why I asked for a naive notion of homotopy.

Answer (score 0):

User Ring Spectra has [answered this question at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155817/what-is-a-homotopy-between-bisimplicial-maps/189120#189120):

> Following Stephan's comment, we can define model structures on s<sup>2</sup>Set, using which we can [define left and right homotopies](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Spalinski/theories.pdf). However, if we look at your maps A×Δ<sup>0,1</sup>→B and A×Δ<sup>1,0</sup>→B, drawing a simple picture allows us to think of A×Δ<sup>1,0</sup>→B as a horizonal homotopy and A×Δ<sup>0,1</sup>→B as vertical homotopy with a suitable orientation of the Cartesian space. A general homotopy can then naively be considered some sort of "composition" of the two - first vertical then horizontal homotopy, or first horizontal then vertical homotopy. But the best one to go with would be the one defined by a chosen model structure on s<sup>2</sup>Set.